# Postfix transport map always using catchall definition

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

Hoping one of the Postfix experts on here can help me debug an issue I am having with transport maps.  I've gone through a the recommend list of questions to try and resolve my issue with no luck.

First the problem:
I need to use a different STMP server (relay host) depending on destination email address.

I created a transport file under **/etc/postfix/transport** (version 2.10)

added the following entries

```
sender1@domainA.com      smtp:[SMTP_for_domainA.com]
sender2@secondDomain.com smtp:[SMTP_for_secondDomain.com
*                        smtp:[Default_SMTP_catch_all]
```

I then ran the following command  **postmap /etc/postfix/transport** and restarted the postfix service.

Now, whenever I try to send email to sender1 or sender2 it always uses the the relay host defined under the * (catchall).

I am able to telnet to both and send email.  I'm also no clear whether I should leave the relayhost= argument out of my **main.cf** file?  Relatively new to Postfix so I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `transport_maps` in `main.cf`, and *remove* `relayhost`. It sounds like you haven't done either of these.

```
 transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have the transport_maps defined, in addition to the relayhost entry.  I will try removing the relayhost= and see if that helps.  Thanks again!